# Ordering parts for fridge is there difference between 1 or 1A or 1B

Tags: refrigerator

My fridge's seal (gasket) cracked and I'm trying to buy new ones from sears.  There is a couple options

for freezer door:

```
#1  Door
#1A Door
#1B Door
```

for fridge door:

```
#2  Door
#2A Door
#2B Door
```

Do all of these fit interchangeably and I just pick any and it would work?

https://www.searspartsdirect.com/model/5qzr5ifzgn-000582/kenmore-25360602413-refrigerator-parts

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the number (1 or 2) is your standard white gasket, while 1B/2B refers to the black version, and 1A/2A appears to refer to a grey version.  The black and grey likely go with the stainless steel version of the model.